# Text align did not work with bootstrap

Tags: html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div style="text-align=!">
<ul>
<li style="float:left;"><a href="">Sample</a></li>
<li><a href="">Sample</a></li>
<li><a href="">Sample</a></li>
<li><a href="">Sample</a></li>
<li><a href="">Sample</a></li>
<li><a href="">Sample</a></li>
<li><a href="">Sample</a></li>
<li><a href="">Sample</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `text-align=!` ?

Comment: What is your question? Don't just post code but also tell us what you want from us.

Answer (score 1):

```
style="text-align:right !important;" //right or left
```

Press f12 in your browser ,`firefox +21` or `chrome` And debug it!!!
or right click and >> inspect element.

Comment: sorry i already try it but it's not work correcktly(M.Eskandari)

Comment: Press f12 in your browser ,firefox +21 or chrome And debug it!!!
or right click and >> inspect element.